# How to uninstall Advance security on oracle 11

Tags: oracle

I tried since many days to uninstall Advanced security without export/Drop/create/Import database. but no way.
May One help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[How To Check if Oracle Advanced Security Option is Installed ? (Doc ID 549989.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=549989.1)

> Oracle product development has decided that starting with Oracle 11g
>   Oracle Advanced Security Option will be installed by default when
>   installing Enterprise Edition . **There is no way to uninstall or to**
>   **install it.** The reason behind this is that Oracle Advanced Security
>   Options are integrated at network adapter level and it is not
>   appropriate to tweak network adapters after database installation.

Comment: Thanks @Balazs for your answer , but I would not find the Advanced Security any more in the table DBA_FEATURE_USAGE_STATISTICS.